# Css text won't load background url images on website?

Tags: html, css

I used notepad++ with html5 and css3. The problem is that the css isn't loading the images, though in the editor it did. I need help. here's my text for one of the images named content, and yes the content tag is on purpose since it's id:

```
#content{
  width:900px; 
  height:600px; 
  background:url(images/content.png); 
  border-radius:20px; 
}
```

So, the folder is on desktop, it's named images and the image is a png named content. It worked on the editor but it's not showing up on the website. On the website it's just showing the grey background.
I took screenshots of it working in edit viewer and it on the actual website.

http://postimg.org/image/mdeso350h/ -- looks fine on edit viewer
http://postimg.org/image/gb75xlgkh/ -- not working on website

Comment: The image `images/content.png` needs to be available relative to the css in the server. please verify if you can access the image as is w.r.t. you css serving server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use quotes for linking images like;

```
background-image: url("images/content.png");
```

And inside your root folder in your server (in x10host.com), use file manager to create a folder named `images` where you have uploaded your file `index.html`, and then you can see `index.html` file and `images` folder in a single place. Then upload your images to `images` folder. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check the file path of css and the images.,
I think this is your file structure

`--folder
   ----index.html
   ----name.css
   ----content.png`

so, just try that `background:url(content.png);` this will help you

incase your file structure like

`--folder
   ----index.html
   ----name.css
   ----images/content.png`

in this case your style works fine `background:url(images/content.png);`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes design tools tend to save file extensions capitalized (.PNG for example), and not every server is aware of that, so you should be.
Check your folder location of the image as well.